# How can I lazily depend on an AAR that created by a task?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm building a library, and I want my sample app to consume the AAR directly from the release build of my library. This allows us to test proguarding of the library module in the sample app.

```
:my-libary
:sample-app
```

In `:sample-app`'s `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        "../my-libary/build/outputs/aar"
    }
}

dependencies {
  // we've added a flavor named "binary" to support this 
  binaryImplementation(name: "my-libary-release", ext: 'aar')
}
```

The problem is, the `my-libary-release.aar` file does not exist until `:my-library:assembleRelease` is run.

The following hacky workaround works, but fails when `android.enableJetifier=true`.

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
  def taskName = task.name.toLowerCase()
  if (taskName.toLowerCase().contains("binary")) {
      // Prepare libs as binaries
      task.dependsOn ":my-library:assembleRelease"
  }
}
```

I am guessing that `android.enableJetifier=true` causes the sample app's dependencies to be resolved too early, before the `.aar` gets built, thus causing the build to fail. Here is the failure:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':sample-app:compileBinaryDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':sample:binaryDebugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find :my-library-release:.
     Required by:
         project :sample-app
```

Is there a better way to depend directly on a dynamically generated AAR file created from a gradle task as a dependency?